# Uploadify: Get file id and cancel upload if duplicate is detected

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I am running uploadify in my site. It works as it is intended to do but I want it to automatically cancel uploads if I detected that the file being uploaded is already in the system.

I have a table in the database the logs all of the files that was uploaded. I can just find that file name and if it matched I will tell uploadify to cancel that file.

With that said and done, I am puzzled on how to tell uploadify to cancel automatically.

I would use the event onUploadStart to check if the filename exists in the DB. Then I would use the cancel method as indicated in the documentation. The problem with this is how to get the file id of the active file.

```
$('#file-upload').uploadify({
                'checkExisting' : '<? echo base_url('source/upload/check-exists.php'); ?>',
                'swf'      : '<? echo base_url('source/upload/uploadify.swf'); ?>',
                'uploader' : '<? echo base_url('source/upload/uploadify.php'); ?>',
                'fileTypeDesc' : 'PDF Files',
                'fileTypeExts' : '*.pdf',
                'onUploadComplete' : function (file) {
                    var fileid = file.id;
                    $(this).uploadify('cancel');
                }
                // Put your options here
            });
```

I am not sure if I am doing it correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> just edit these lines

```
'onUploadComplete' : function (file) {
                    $('#file-upload').uploadify('cancel',''+file.id+'');
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`checkExisting`**](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/checkexisting/) option of the uploadify.

As per the official documentation:

> The path to a file that checks whether the name of the file being
>   uploaded currently exists in the destination folder.  The script
>   should return 1 if the file name exists or 0 if the file name does not
>   exist.

To cancel/delete the file after upload is an overhead. Using `checkExisting` you can verify for file existence in the database and return the appropriate value ( 1 or 0 ).